# What is the reason for adding registers four times as shown in the example?

Tags: arrays, mips

I've only just begun to learn MIPS and this particular example has me confused. Particularly adding the registers four times.

Here is the example that I'm talking about:

[image]

What is the purpose of doing **add $t0, $s1, $s1**

and then **add $t0, $t0, $t0** so that you have four times of what **int k** was?

Comment: It looks like they could've done `sll $t0,$s1,2` instead  (`$t0 = $s1 << 2` == `$t0 = $s1 * 4`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's used for the conversion from the int array index (code) to the byte array index (memory).

`k` is the index of the int array in the code. The size of an int is 4 bytes. To load the value from the byte array in memory, you will go to the byte position `k * 4`. Adding happens to be the simplest operation to achieve this.

Comment: but from how I'm viewing it, it looks like you are manipulating what k was originally and making it 28(k was 7 and it's 4 * k) and since the array is only size 12, wouldn't it mean it is accessing memory that is out of bounds?

Comment: The array has 12 _elements_, but each element is one _word_, which is 4 bytes. So the size of the array in bytes is 12*4 = 48.

Comment: @Michael Oh ok, now I see.

Comment: @Michael Ok let's say you didn't add the registers so you can have 4 *k so that you have  v + k instead of v + 4k. What would happen? Would you be accessing a memory location that you're not allowed to or you do access an element in the array but it is not the location that you want?

Comment: You'd be allowed to access the location but the location would be incorrect. You would either get another array index value (if k is divisible by 4), or you would get a value made up of the bytes of two adjacent array elements. For example, if k = 1, you would get the last 3 bytes of the first int, the first byte of the second int, and those 4 bytes would be interpreted as your result.

Comment: @Michael An even better question would be, if the array is a character array instead of an int array, I'm assuming that I won't have to manipulate what k is because a character is 1 byte as oppose to an int array that is 4 btyes so I don't need to perform this intermediate step. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, if it was a character array, you would not need to modify k when accessing memory. Similarly, if it was a larger datatype, such as long, you would need to modify k by multiplying it by 8.

Comment: Alright, it took a while but I think I have basic understanding now.